# How to install Win7 with dual boot in my ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot

I have ubuntu 12.04 and want to install win7 with dual boot because mi CLARO modem (Argentina) doesn`t work with ubuntu. How I do it?

Comment: Luis: Not a duplicate because the order of OS is reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to

- backup the $HOME directory and everything beneath it to an external  device
- verify the backup is good, install Win7, completely erasing Ubuntu in the process
- Once Win7 is installed, then reinstall Ubuntu
- Import your data from the external backup and change the ownership so you can use it

Why? Because Windows will stomp all over Ubuntu when you install it.